# html5 Video tags without calling the quicktime player

Tags: cordova, html5-video

I am a iOS developer. Recently I started learning the PhoneGap. Here is my question:

I wanna do a video player apps using PhoneGap. Of course, by using the video tag, we can easily play a video with the quicktime player. But how can I disable this action (calling out the quicktime player), since I want to use a custom player instead.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This might help knowing some limitation 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

Or similar discussion here on Video.JS
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/37
"On iPhones, Apple has made the decision that all html5 video plays in the fullscreen, native player rather than letting it play inline."