# Phonegap video quicktime player overlay on ios

Tags: ios, video, cordova, mp4, quicktime

I'm developing a Phonegap app, which needs to reproduce some videos, and I need to add some controls over them to do some stuff. It is working nicely on Android, but I'm having issues with the ios version, as it is launching the quicktime player. Even if it is showing the controls which are over the player, is not possible to interact with them, because events are not fireing.

I found some hacky solutions like [this](http://perrymitchell.net/article/interacting-with-overlay-elements-on-html5-video/) or [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/a5hHtfIfwXM), but they are quite old, and I'm hoping to find a better solution for that.

I'm using the html5 video tag, and lets assume, that my phonegap application could be something like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <video controls poster="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg">
        <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <button id="ok">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

[Watch it on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6325n/3/)

I'm looking for a way of integrating mp4 video in phonegap with the possibility of adding more elements, and the user can be able to interact with them.

Maybe the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720023/html5-video-tags-without-calling-the-quicktime-player), could help me aswell.

Many thanks in advance